# Mono MySQL.Data 6.9 Open NotImplementedException

Tags: mysql, exception, mono

Trying to use MySQL.Data in Mono and as soon as I try to connect, make the Open() call, it throws a NotImplemented exception with stack trace:

> at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get () [0x00000] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-04/bockbuild-2017-04/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Management/System.Management/ManagementObjectSearcher.cs:102
>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher:Get () at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.get_OSDetails () [0x00010] in
>   <0a135c8e4d604d948724bf6960583b7f>:0

Anyone seen this?

Using

- .NET Framework 4.7 (target)
- Mono 5.2.0.104
- MySql.Data 6.9.9
- OSX Sierra
- VS 7.1 Preview

**UPDATE** Really weird stuff going here. I took the code over to a Win machine and compiled and ran it there fine. But when I brought the code but to OSX and ran it without compiling (in other words using the binary from Windows) it ran fine connecting without a problem! As soon as I cleaned and rebuilt in OSX same error! Wonder if it has to do with some sort of flag needing to be set.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/0bcbe39b148bb498742fc68416f8293ccd350fb6/mcs/class/System.Management/System.Management/ManagementObjectSearcher.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering.

It turns out that I had a System.Exception Catchpoint enabled causing debug to break on that line although the code was handling the exception.

So all I needed to do was to disable the Catchpoint and done.